# JQuery Datatable,add row

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a Datatable that has column definitions defined when initialising it.
Column definitions are basically coming from ajax data.
Now I want to add a new row to the existing Datatable on click of a button.

There are three columns, and I want to add 3 rows with input type field.

How can I achieve that on a button click ?

Comment: Do you mean like this: [Add rows example](https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html)? Basically, use `row.add()` or `rows.add()`.

Comment: For a Stack Overflow answer see [how add row in datatable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52288354/how-add-row-in-datatable) and [similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=datatable+add+row+site%3Astackoverflow.com).

Comment: If none of these answers meet your needs, then please [edit] your question to provide sample code, showing what you have tried, and where you are stuck.

Comment: Yes correct,I mean like that (1st point) . But the difference is, while initialising Datatable,I have defined columnDefs,  so the code written in that example, it's showing me column error

Comment: OK - see my 2nd and 3rd comments.